# Select 2 checkbox and be able to download the file in thingspeak?

Tags: jquery

I have two checkbox and want to select two fields, so that when I click download. I can be able to get two fields from the file format. Notice if you use the url of my thingspeak channel I can able to get 2 fields. Now I want to use same scenario in my jquery.

```js
// checking for neither of the two feeds.
$(function() {
  $("#download").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('#temperature', '#illuminance').is(':checked')) {      window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/feeds/last.csv?api_key=F35GLOFJ8L99D0OM');
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#download").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class ="custom-control-input" id="temperature">
  <label class = "custom-control-label" for="temperature">Temperature</label>
</div>

<div class = "custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type = "checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="illuminance">
  <label class = "custom-control-label" for = "illuminance">Illuminance</label>
<div class="form-group"><br>
  <div class="col-md-1.9 text-center">
    <button id="download" name="download" class="btn btn-warning" >Download</button><br>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I think that you should give us more details, it's not clear yet. What means to get 2 fields,  there's only a single api link that you posted?

Answer (score 0):

Your query selector is wrong.

```
if($('#temperature', '#illuminance').is(':checked'))
```

Synatx is: *$('selector1,selector2,selectorN')*

Try this..

```
if($('#temperature,#illuminance').is(':checked'))
```

[Live demo](https://repl.it/repls/MysteriousColdDeprecatedsoftware)

Note: Also sometimes browsers blocks window from opening.

Reference

[jQuery - Multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector)

Comment: Thanks mates, i ran a test on my side, all my two fields return correct data from the file format.

Comment: if you want an order of them to be selected, how do you go about creating? Meaning, user first select temperature on its own, then after select 2 after download. im trying that logic now.

Comment: you mean by default temperature is checked?

Comment: // checking for for each feeds.
  $(function() {
  $("#download").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   if($('#temperature').is(':checked')){
     window.open("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/1.csv?results=10");
   }
    if($('#illuminance').is(':checked')){
    window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/2.csv?results=10');
      }
    if($('#button-state').is(':checked')){
    window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/8.csv?results=10');
      }
    });
  }); They must be in order together with this one

Comment: But it doesn't matter since they are inside click function. Once you click download button, It'll execute all the if statements if condition met.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still couldn't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Give me some more details on what you're trying to do. So I could help you.

Comment: First i want my Jquery first allow each checking and download file. Second when checking 2(temp, illuminance) it must be able to download one file not multiple file format. Thirdly same applies with them all(temp, illuminance, button-state) in one file format(dont worry about URL, have use doc from thingspeak).

Comment: Try this.. {  e.preventDefault();
   var isTemp = $('#temperature').is(':checked');
   var isIlluminance = $('#illuminance').is(':checked');
   var isButtonState = $('#button-state').is(':checked');
   if (isTemp && isIlluminance && isButtonState) { window.open('/fields/8.csv?results=10'); }
   if (isTemp && isIlluminance) { window.open('/fields/2.csv?results=10'); }
   if (isTemp) { window.open("/fields/…); } }

Comment: LOL mate is is possible for you to come to SA? LOL its works like a charm mate, thanks so much.

Comment: Cool.. Always happy to help!